# iOS game center matchmaking, friends only?

Tags: iphone, ios, gamekit, game-center, multiplayer

I was just curious, is it possible to make a game center match that you can only invite friends to?  (i.e. no random matchups) How would you code that?

Comment: I am having one problem that when i start my game with 3player in the multiplayer game.where number of maximum player =4 minimum player =2
now i started a game with 3player and when 1player get disconnected then other 2player also get disconnected y this happen?
Is there any solution regarding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is probably to make a own custom GKMatchmakerViewController that only show friends during the match making.

Comment: was hoping i wouldn't have to do that ;)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [GKMatchRequest](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKMatchRequest_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) has the capability to do this using either the playerGroup or playersToInvite property.

Comment: playerGroup won't work for this as it's simply an `NSInteger` or `NSUInteger`

Answer (score 0):

It only works in OS 4.2.. which in my opinion would be a small group of people.. So just take note..

Here's the link: [Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Users/Users.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH8-SW6)

Scroll all the way down and you will find your answer..